# iOS spring animation on UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, animation, uitableview

I have custom UITableViewCell in my app. When I tap on this cell I would like to this cell perform some spring effect animation from left to right. How can I do such animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `animateWithDuration: animation:` you can do some neat stuff.

It is used like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:(float duration) animation^{(block)}];
```

`Duration` is the time it will take to perform the `animation`, and the `block` is what is suppose to happen within the `duration`, for example:

```
cell.center = CGPointMake(cell.center.x+50, cell.center);
```

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 7.0 and later you can use `+animateWithDuration:delay:usingSpringWithDamping:initialSpringVelocity:options:animations:completion:`.